# Паскаль в питон

Tags: python, pascal

Помогите пожалуйста перевести паскаль в питон. Буду очень благодарен. Вот код:

````pascal
var
  N, i, NumFirstMax, NumLastMin: byte;
  elem, max, min: integer;

begin
  write('N = ');
  readln(N);
  writeln('Введите ', N, ' целых чисел:');
  for i := 1 to N do
  begin
    read(elem);
    if i = 1 then begin
      max := elem; NumFirstMax := 1;
      min := elem; NumLastMin := 1
    end
    else begin
     
      if min >= elem then begin
        min := elem; 
        NumLastMin := i  
      end;
   
      if max < elem then begin
        max := elem; 
        NumFirstMax := i
      end
    end
  end;
  writeln('Ответ: ', NumLastMin:3);
  readln
end. ```
````

Вот мой код:

```py
N = int(input())
for i in range(N):
    elem = int(input())
    if i == 1:
        max = elem
        min = elem
        NumFirstMax = 1
        NumLastMin = 1
    else:
        if min >= elem:
            min = elem
            NumlastMin = i
        if max < elem:
            max = elem
            NumFirstMax = 1
print(NumLastMin)
```

Но выдаёт не те ответы. На вход:

5

36

712

11

104

58

Вывод должен быть: 3

Выводит: 1

Comment: И что, вы в питоне цикла фор или оператора if не напишете?

Comment: я например не знаю что такое then или := перед переменной. Я вообще плохо паскаль знаю

Comment: Кажется, это такой способ обойти ограничение на код в учебных задачах. В вопросе опишите решаемую задача и приведите код на Питоне с попыткой её решения.

Comment: Ну эта задача крайне проста. Нужно её сформулировать и буквально реализовать на целевом языке. Код на Паскале, в общем-то и не нужен, т.к. ввод данных всё равно по-другому будет происходить. then ничего не значит, это просто часть оператора иф (если... то...), := - присвоение

Comment: Главное отличие, что в паскале цикл от 1, а в питоне `range` дает список от нуля.  Поэтому начальное заполнение переменных при `i==1` не работает. Поменяйте на 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
N = int(input())
for i in range(1, N + 1):
    elem = int(input())
    if i == 1:
        max = elem
        min = elem
        NumFirstMax = 1
        NumLastMin = 1
    else:
        if min >= elem:
            min = elem
            NumLastMin = i
        if max < elem:
            max = elem
            NumFirstMax = i
print(NumLastMin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ввод данных оформить отдельно, а потом работать с обычным списком

```
arr = [5, 36, 712, 11, 104, 58]
max_ = min_ = arr[0]

for idx, item in enumerate(arr):
    if min_ >= item:
        min_ = item
        last_min = idx
    if max_ < item:
        max_ = item
        first_max = idx

print(max_, min_, first_max, last_min)
```